# Why we use web methods of web services, instead of web form funcions

Tags: javascript, web-services, call, code-behind, webmethod

There's a period of time that I changed my web programming method.
I develop my **functions** as **web methods** in some **Web Services**, then I call them in my website's UI using **javascript**.
My question is why do we use **web services**? I think it's better to write these functions in the **code behind of original page** and call them with **javascript**. Isn't it better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webservices can be called from any platform, but the code in the behind of web forms can not.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question: if you have some functions which are used by different pages, it is more efficient to put them in a separate resource. The resource is downloaded only once and your pages are lighter.

Comment: So if these functions be used only in one page, can I put them in the code-behind of the original page?

Comment: I want to know using web service instead of web forms, has any effect on the performance of this programming method?